# how do i get rid of the json errors : line 2-4 Comments are not permitted in JSON. line 62 char 2 end of file expected

Tags: json, visual-studio

i am working on learning more about json code and how to get rid of the json errors and i am just working from the script i would like to make a better script. i did do everything i could think of to get rid of the errors without changing the language in visual studios, what is your solution to get rid of the errors?
here are the error message in visual studio:
line 2-4 Comments are not permitted in JSON.
line 62 char 2 end of file expected
the following json script is used to make the c++ debugger run and is used to enable visual studio to identifiy c++ errors. i am just tweaking it.

```
{
          line 2 // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    line 3    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    line 4    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [

            {
                "name": "(gdb) Attach",
                "type": "cppdbg",
                "request": "attach",
                "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
                "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
                "MIMode": "gdb",
                "miDebuggerPath": "/path/to/gdb",
                "setupCommands": [
                    {
                        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                        "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                        "ignoreFailures": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
    "customLaunchSetupCommands": [
        { "text": "target-run", "description": "run target", "ignoreFailures": false }
      ],
      "launchCompleteCommand": "exec-run",
    "windows :gdb"
     :"C:\\MinGw\\bin\\gdb.exe"
      }
    ]

                ,"name": "(gdb) Bash on Windows Launch",
                "type": "cppdbg",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
                "args": [],
                "stopAtEntry": false,
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "environment": [],
                "externalConsole": true,
                "pipeTransport": {
                    "debuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
                    "pipeProgram": "${env:windir}\\system32\\bash.exe",
                    "pipeArgs": ["-c"],
                    "pipeCwd": ""
                },
                "setupCommands": [
                    {
                        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                        "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                        "ignoreFailures": true
                    }
      [enter image description here][1]          ],"customLaunchSetupCommands": [
        { "text": "target-run", "description": "run target", "ignoreFailures": false }
      ],

      "launchCompleteCommand": "exec-run",
    "windows" : "gdb,"
        ,"miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGw\\bin\\gdb.exe"
    line 62 }[ 
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

to get rid of the line 2-4 Comments are not permitted in JSON. remove a backslash on 2 of those lines and a colon. remove the brackets at line 62.